# Why is my for-loop only counting to one object in the JSON-response?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, restsharp

I'm trying to make a map with map-annotations which are being generated from a REST-JSON response. I've succeeded with making one, the JSON response contains two objects. Why are only one printed out?

I'm using RestSharp and Xamarin.iOS.

Here's a [Gist-clone](https://gist.github.com/jackbillstrom/50ab073e241bc1cbce3b) of the original respones

The function that grabs the data to later-on make map-annotations on our map:

```
Action getAllMarkers = () => {
    var client = new RestClient("http://www.example.com/");
    var request = new RestRequest(String.Format("api/?function=searchByName&key=&name=Sundsvall"));

    client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
        JsonValue data = JsonValue.Parse(response.Content);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Count; i++){
                Double lat = data["result"][i]["lat"];
                Double lng = data["result"][i]["lng"];
                String name = data["result"][i]["title"];
                String adress = data["result"][i]["adress"];
                var store = new BasicMapAnnotation (new CLLocationCoordinate2D(lat, lng), name, adress);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
                    InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
                        // manipulate UI controls
                        map.AddAnnotation(store);
                    });
                }
            });
        };

    getAllMarkers();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.Count` is 1, because there is one top level "result" node in your json.  Use `data["result"].Count` instead.

Answer (score 1):

your `result` is main array in which rest of the data is so use:`data["result"].Count` instead of `data.Count`